# How to get first/last IP address of CIDR using ipaddr module

Tags: python, ip-address, cidr

The brute force approach:

```
from ipaddr import IPv4Network
n = IPv4Network('10.10.128.0/17')
all = list(n.iterhosts()) # will give me all hosts in network
first,last = all[0],all[-1] # first and last IP
```

I was wondering how I would get the first and last IP address from a CIDR without having to iterate over a potentially very large list to get the first and last element?

I want this so I can then generate a random ip address in this range using something like this:

```
socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('>I', random.randint(int(first),int(last))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try netaddr instead, in particular the indexing section.

https://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/tutorial_01.html#indexing

```
from netaddr import *
import pprint

ip = IPNetwork('10.10.128.0/17')

print "ip.cidr = %s" % ip.cidr
print "ip.first.ip = %s" % ip[0]
print "ip.last.ip = %s" % ip[-1]
```

Comment: Oops...looks like ipaddr module supports this method as well! I should have tried that. I used ipaddr over netaddr as I found the former had more reliable operations for checking overlapping CIDRs.

Answer (score 10):

From Python 3.3, you can use the [`ipaddress` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network)

You could use it like this:

```
import ipaddress

n = ipaddress.IPv4Network('10.10.128.0/17')
first, last = n[0], n[-1]
```

`__getitem__` is implemented, so it won't generate any large lists.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/ipaddress.py#L634

Comment: I like this solution because it uses standard libraries, and is Pythonic precisely because of ```__getitem__``` and the efficiency of getting first and last (thanks to @bsa for pointing this out).  The OP @aaa90210 isn't precise about exactly what the application is so OP may have wanted the network and broadcast which this will return. For my application I wanted first and last IP in the range and ```first, last = n[1], n[-2]``` worked well for me.

Answer (score 4):

The python 3 ipaddress module is the more elegant solution, imho. And, by the way, it works fine, but the ipaddress module doesn't return exactly the first and last free ip addresses at indexes [0,-1], but respectively the network address and the broadcast address.

The first and last free and assignable addresses are rather

```py
import ipaddress

n = ipaddress.IPv4Network('10.10.128.0/17')
first, last = n[1], n[-2]
```

which will  return **10.10.128.1** as first and **10.10.255.254** instead of 10.10.128.0 and 10.10.255.255